# Saving model object into SQL DB

Tags: sql, database, cocoa

I am reading several tutorials on how to use an SQL database with Cocoa, and it seems quite easy. I already took a look at a few wrappers too, but I can't find anywhere a way to save objects.

Is it correct to conform my model object to the `NSCoding` protocol, and just save the `NSKeyedArchiver`  as an `NSData` object into the DB?

Should I do differently? Which is the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSKeyedArchive too, but is not the best solution imho. Is like storing all data in a platform independent "database" an xml file. It wasn't created for that, it in't optimized for that.
I would create a NSSqlArchieve and map those fields which I want as how I want in native database, because: in different databases you can have custom fields, custom type fields , which myabe improve a select or other database operation. Or you just want to take advatage of some system table/data and can't find a mapping or is to slow or other problems.

NSData can be stored / retrieved to a Blob/Clob, since is binary data. 
But all data convert to binary format and store it to database.... why to store there and why not into a file. Database was invented to store and make query from data.

Comment: so you would suggest to save them with the nssqlarchieve, have u any good tutorial or link for that? i never used it...

Comment: no, read again.  I don't suggest to make it with that.  I am telling it could be made, if you are lazy to make a work as how is needed, but isn't that the good way. You should write NSSqlArchieve your class and do what is needed the business logic at least. More closer to native platform , to the hardware higher is the performance!

Comment: can you please refer me to some link to read more about it? i'm new with databases so i'm a bit lost

Comment: this will not work for you. If you can't google it, than you can't make it alone and need more help than 2 links. You have to decide the architecture first: store data on phone or in remote database. If local, than sql lite , or simple internal storage or an xml, if remote than direct access to database or via http post and a webservice. Every option has advantage and disadvantages. Best is what the project needs and I don't know that. If you are at school ( no money) than ask a friend, pay a cola and a sandwich, because he need to explain to you a lot:) if you have income already than pay it

Comment: there's no friend to ask :( let's make 2 different example apps.
1) app where you store your fav recipes and you have classes like ( ingredient, recipe ). i would save locally. and considering i probably wouldn't save over 400 recipes, sqlite would be better than coredata. which technique would be better to save my models? save the object directly or just save the raw data in several tables? ( table RECIPE with ingredientID(array of int), duration(int), level(int), description(string). table INGREDIENT with name(string), img(string), id(int) )

Comment: 2) let's say we have an app for an online store where i want people to make reservation, so i need to use a remote database. i would have classes like ( person, id, product ) which technique would be best? nscoding? nssqlarchieve? core data?

Comment: 1) to store the fav recipes it is needed to store a recipeId only. So that requires a few bytes in internal memory usage, Google it how to do it, there are plenty of examples and is easy. All recipes - if the user is not allowed to modify- are hardcoded into app. You will select and choose recipes by ingredients without database, only from memory( data collections). 2) for registration/reservation need a php website with mysql databases;: user is allowed to make reqistration via web, or by phone calling webservice, after autherntification. I hop problem solved!

Comment: my question is, when i save them on my phone ( let's say my app let me save and edit recipes, but won't need to save them online cause it will only keep for myself ) i can use sql. but how do i save the object in the sql? do i create a table recipe and place primitive types or i use keyed object and save it as nsdata?

Comment: I think I have answered a few question for you already. This is going to be a long discussion and no reward for me, not even a 15 repu from accepting my answer. I would suggest to try the chat or ask for a consultant,

Comment: i was planning on giving, just was waiting for the answer i needed, or probably you wouldnt notice it was still an open case :)